# Crystal Report "Logon failed..." Error when trying to navigation to next page

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a web-based Crystal Report that loads successfully, but when i try to navigate to the next page using the toolbar at the top of my CrystalReportViewer then i get the following error:

"Logon failed. Details: ADO Error Code: 0x Source: Microsoft SQL Native Client Description: Login failed for user 'sa'. SQL State: 28000 Native Error: Error in File C:\DOCUME~1\SOFTLITE\ASPNET\LOCALS~1\Temp\ClientReport {02A69EDD-9B03-4490-B3A2-5E5E5F5592D9}.rpt: Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters."

Any ideas on how to overcome this problem are most welome.

Thanks IA

Answer (score 3):

I think i have resolved this issue (in my scenario at least).

Originally my code looked like:

if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    LoadReport();
}

so i dropped the "if (!Page.IsPostBack)" part meaning that it loads the report data on every postback (i.e. click on the CrystalReportViewer toolbar) an it's working.

Comment: Thanks, it was a simple, but annoying problem!