# Crystal Report error Missing parameter values when move to next page

Tags: asp.net, mysql, parameters, crystal-reports

My Crystal Report works fine in the first page but when i click on the next page button the report doesn't load and gives Missing parameter values error. Can anybody help me to solve this problem.

My current coding is given below.

```
protected void ddlStudent_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        GenerateReport();

}

protected void GenerateReport()
{
    //Create report document
    ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument();

    //Load crystal report made in design view
    crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("Reports/PhotoGallery.rpt"));

    //Set DataBase Login Info
    crystalReport.SetDatabaseLogon("root", "pwd", @"localhost", "nsis");

    //Provide parameter values
    crystalReport.SetParameterValue("adno", adNo);

    crvReportViewer.ReportSource = crystalReport;

}
```

Comment: Where is "adno" coming from? Don't see it anywhere in your code.

Comment: it is set from the dropdownlist index changed event and i rechecked it. parameter is passed correctly. Plus the report loads nicely in the first page.error happens when i move to second page.

Comment: Similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290208/crystal-report-logon-failed-error-when-trying-to-navigation-to-next-page

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call GenerateReport(); method in page load as well try following

```
 protected void ddlStudent_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            GenerateReport();
            ViewState["ReportLoad"] = "Load";
        }

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ViewState["ReportLoad"] != null)
            {
                GenerateReport();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I solved the problem.

What i did was adding this kinda code to crystal report viewer's navigate event.

objDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
objDiscreteValue.Value = adnumber;
objParameterField = CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo["adno"];
objParameterField.CurrentValues.Add(objDiscreteValue);
CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo.Add(objParameterField);
Thank you very much everybody who tried to help me :)